# JS: bind function fail passing arguments in recursions

Tags: javascript, recursion, bind, alert

For instance:

```
function GoAlert(text){
    alert(text)
    setTimeout(GoAlert.bind(text),100);
}

GoAlert("Hello World");
```

The first alert says `Hello World`, but the next ones says `undefined`. Why?

Comment: You have not bound the argument in your `.bind()` call https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), the 1st argument you provide specifies the value of `this` for the function.

> #### Syntax
>
> `fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`

To provide a value for the 1st parameter (`text`), it should be the 2nd argument (`arg1`).

```
setTimeout(GoAlert.bind(undefined, text), 100);
```

Comment: And then `function(){GoAlert(text)}` is shorter.